# Marketing Cloud Analytics Builder custom data send

Tags: marketing-cloud, analytics

**Problem statement:**- I have a third party application wherein I need to capture the click event and send the event data to marketing cloud analytics builder to generate a custom view in the builder. I cannot find any documentation which states that it is possible or not.

I have already read through the basic documentation for Analytics Builder provided in the mentioned link [Analytics Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_anb_analytics_builder.htm&type=5).

**Can anyone confirm if this can be performed or not? and if yes, can you please provide a supporting document for the same?**